# xpath not grabbing contents

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have the following xpath query:

```
//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="post-container"]//div[contains(@class,"post-content")]//p
```

I'm trying to grab the article contents from the following URL:

http://gawker.com/u-s-pulls-ahead-in-taylor-swift-education-continues-t-1445261687

It doesn't seem to be working. What I was expecting was an array of `DOMNodes` with all of the `p` tags.

Here's my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$urlText = file_get_contents($url);
$domDocument->loadHTML($urlText);
$finder = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$xpath = '//div[@class="row"]//div[@class="post-container"]//div[contains(@class,"post-content")]//p';
$xpathContents = $finder->query($xpath);
```

**NOTE: I need to use `file_get_contents` for extra parsing logic**

Comment: have you tried this: `//div[contains(@class,"post-content")]//p`

Comment: @tttony yes. i'm really confused on why its not returning content. the xpaths are correct. i did notice that there is an attribute in the p element `data-textannotation-id="234d4be1de6ac84e6326becfa3459ee9"`. Do you think thats affecting the xpath?

Comment: Start simplifying the xpath. start deleting terms until you DO start getting something back. there's where your xpath went off the rails.

Comment: @tttony the article was the issue. i tried a different one using your xpath and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is thanks to some invalid `<script>` tag that is included just under the first `<p>` tag. It is closing tags inside some document.write code, which I am guessing is "messing with DOMDocument / DOMXPath's head".

It's not too classy, but you can avoid that by loading the document you have read into SimpleXML, and doing a modified XPath query based on the data-textannontation-id (which avoids the nasty script tag).

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$urlText = file_get_contents('g');
$domDocument->loadHTML($urlText);
$sxe = simplexml_import_dom($domDocument);
$xpath = '//*[@data-textannotation-id]';
$xpathContents = $sxe->xpath($xpath);

// What do you know, there is 8 items here... woop woop!
print_r($xpathContents);

// bonus points, here is the text output!
$text = '';
foreach ($xpathContents as $node) {
    $text .= trim((string)dom_import_simplexml($node)->textContent);
}
echo $text;
```